"When you do something, something else has already been done" - what's the correct tense?
I'd like to ask about the verb tenses in the following sentence:
"When you call from the Help tab in our app, your identity has already been verified and you will get through quicker."
Is this correct? Saying "when you do something, something else has already been done" sounds wrong to me but I can't find the grammatical rule for this anywhere.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Yours is a "peculiar" example, where the precise temporal relationship between the two actions calling and verifying is inherently unclear. The presence of the word already simply confuses things even more, since it wouldn't normally make much sense to say a caller's identity has already been verified before any contact has been made.

Compare, for example, When you light a cigarette in a British pub, you have already broken the law. That's a pretty unusual choice of phrasing compared to ...you are breaking the law or you will be breaking the law. In your context, I suggest ...your identity is / will be automatically verified and you will get through quicker would be more idiomatic.

When you log into the app, your identity is verified. So later, when you use the "call" option within the app, your identity has already been verified. Nothing to do with language, just software engineering.

Thank you both for your answers. FumbleFingers' suggestion is a good one!

Yes, your example is correct.

When you call from the Help tab in our app, your identity has already been verified and you will get through quicker.

However, I think it sounds better when you reorder the two:

Your identity has already been verified when you call from the Help tab, so you should get through more quickly.


Thanks for your suggestion, as with the ones above, it's a really good one.

OP's sentence is:

When you call from the Help tab in our app, your identity has already been verified.

The sentence is not grammatically incorrect but it is awkwardly phrased.
The first clause (when you call) the second clause (already been verified) seems logically inconsistent because it means the verification happened before you called.
This can be corrected by rephrasing the sentence.
Your identity has already been verified in the app, so when you call from the help tab you will get through quicker.
In this sentence it is clear that the verification was done in the app  before you called. Now you will get through quicker because verification need not be done again.

Thanks for your reply and the rephrasing. This helps a lot.

@MrDakash Is it your own sentence or from an instruction manual?

it's a sentence from our company's website, written by a non-native speaker.
